# Get All Tasks In Outlook WinForms

Tags: vb.net, outlook, mapi

I will accept C# code as well. Will just convert it to VB.NET.

I'm having trouble retrieving tasks from outlook.

I have an application that writes a task to outlook.

The application can also mark a task as completed... but this is where my problem comes in.

What I want to achieve at the end is to mark a task as completed in my application and then it should also be marked as completed in outlook.

This is the code I have tried so far to retrieve the tasks, but now I dont know how to iterate through them to be able to mark a specific task as completed:

```
Dim namespce As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim tasks As Outlook.Items
Dim oApp = New Outlook.Application

namespce = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
tasks = namespce.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks).Items

For Each task As Object In tasks
    'From here on I dont know any more
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# code:

```
foreach(Outlook.TaskItem task in tasks)
{
   bool isCompleeted = //Check if your task is compleeted in your application you could use EntryID property to identify a task 
   if(isCompleeted == true && task.Status != OlTaskStatus.olTaskComplete)
   {
       task.MarkComplete();
       task.Save();
   }
}
```